# Shutting down computer from terminal in debian buster

Tags: debian

What is the command for shutting down the computer and rebooting it using terminal in Debian buster?
I am using KDE version.

Comment: In the time that it took you to post this question, you could have found the answer using Google several times over.

Comment: I tried that. Most of them said to try reboot and poweroff. But when I try those the terminal says "bash: reboot: command not found" and "bash: poweroff: command not found".

Comment: It's `sudo reboot` and `sudo poweroff`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. As user root:

```
# reboot
```

The reboot command is only available for the root user. If you are logged in as a normal user try it with sudo:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux documentation says:

```
halt, poweroff, reboot - Halt, power-off or reboot the machine

These are legacy commands available for compatibility only.
```

The approved method is currently **shutdown**

For those crisis moments, google **Raising Elephants**

Answer (score 0):

The `reboot`, and `shutdown` commands (`shutdown -r`) are in `/usr/sbin` (admin commands that usually require root privs/`sudo` and may not be in your regular path, if you are a plain user.

On modern system they are aliases for `systemctl [verb]`: `sudo systemctl reboot`.